# output repeated for each line

Tags: c

http://ideone.com/GKxcj
this is my code. I have a question about the output so when i tried to print output to file it show me this ouput :
http://codepad.org/LvaboydT
 as you can see from this output that the total column was repeated for every line why is this happen the calcdata  function seems good to me. If something was wrong in the caldata function can anyone explain what was wrong to me ?
thanks

Comment: It might be useful to debug this by adding some `printf()` statements when the `total` value is calculated -- just as a check to see if the oddity is due to the output or the calculation.

Comment: i cant do that because it seems to have undefined behavior somewhere which doesn't output to the screen even if i use printf, also i could get the output file to run on my system> I got the output from someone else system when they run it on their system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I go through your code and one thing seems to be weird. If i understand clearly, each table correspond to a skater.

For each row you have a base, some score and a total score.
In your print function we can clearly see that:

skater[i].baseval[j] print the base val for skater i and row j

Then the score list is displayed with skater[i].score[j][k] where k is the score index in the array.

However when printing the total score you display skater[i].total_score which is a unique value. So it is normal that is the same for each row of the table for one given skater.

If you want a total score for each row, you just have to transform skater[i].total_score to an array then compute the total score and add it to the righ row (like you did for the base score)

Edit: changed wrong variable name

Regards

Comment: well i wasn't display tech_score as total score. I calculated tech score separately from total score.

Comment: Sorry i meant total_score: fprintf(fpOut,"  %5.2f", skater[i].total_score); You see you only have one total score for the skater, so it is natural that it is the same for each row

Comment: well may be total_score should be an array because as it is now i only have 1 total_score for each skater

Comment: Yeah so it is normal that the output for your total column is the same for each row.